# I can't install bootcamp

Tags: mac, bootcamp, mojave, storage, error

It says I have to have at least 42 GB or more but as you can see I have 55 GB available. Tried looking online for solutions but all they say is time machine but I have never used this and the "Backup Automatically" is not selected.
[image]

Comment: Could you add to your question the model/year of your Mac? Also, what version of Windows are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

The free space required by the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows is larger than what is actually required. One question where this is documented is [Mojave bootcamp assistant limits partition size](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359351/mojave-bootcamp-assistant-limits-partition-size). The answer to this question was to use the Disk Utility to create a partition for Windows, then install Windows the same way as any ordinary PC owner. The Boot Camp Assistant was only used to download the Windows Support Software.

In your case, I would first make sure all space being consumed by Time Machine is recovered. This can be done by executing the command given below in a Terminal Application Window. Basically, the command tries to reclaim any space taken by Time Machine by asking for a lot of space back. Once you have finished executing this command, go back and try using the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows.

```
tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999
```

Other space issues related to installing Windows are documented in the accepted answer to the question: [Installing Windows on MBP 2015 (Mojave) Using Boot Camp, Error: Not enough space!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359921/installing-windows-on-mbp-2015-mojave-using-boot-camp-error-not-enough-space/359927#359927).

Comment: Yes I thought about doing that but I was unsure if that works. Should I give it a shot?

Comment: Yes, if the `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999` command did not help.