# BootCamp The startup disk does not have enough space to be partitioned

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition, mojave

I am currently trying to install bootcamp, however i am experiencing the following error: 
"The startup disk does not have enough space to be partitioned." 
"You must have at least 42GB of free space available."

I have checked my storage and i have 62GB available storage. 
I have checked and my Time machine is switched off and I have also tried sudo tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 999999999999 in terminal and still not working.
I would really appreciate if someone can help.
I am using macOS Mojave. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The free space required by the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows is larger than what is actually required. One question where this is documented is [Mojave bootcamp assistant limits partition size](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359351/mojave-bootcamp-assistant-limits-partition-size). The answer to this question was to use the Disk Utility to create a partition for Windows, then install Windows the same way as any ordinary PC owner. The Boot Camp Assistant was only used to download the Windows Support Software.

Other space issues related to installing Windows are documented in the accepted answer to the question: [Installing Windows on MBP 2015 (Mojave) Using Boot Camp, Error: Not enough space!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359921/installing-windows-on-mbp-2015-mojave-using-boot-camp-error-not-enough-space/359927#359927).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am not sure if I know how to do it, but will try to find out.